# How can I add the email,phone,date and name in a row? I want to add to a row and that too through code.how to add the parsed data to a table layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

how to add the parsed data to a table layout? 
I want to do this through code and not through xml.
where should I create the table layout and set the parsed data to it?
As I cannot create UI in Doinbackground method. Please help me.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Context context;
        String response = "";

         for (String url : urls) {
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response1;

        try {
            response1 = client.execute(httpGet);

            Log.e("url", response.toString());
            HttpEntity entity = response1.getEntity();
            // Log.e("response", entity.toString());
            is = entity.getContent();
            // Log.e("entity",is.toString());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("RES", result.toString());

            JSONArray jarray;

            try {
                jarray = new JSONArray(result);

                Email = new String[jarray.length()];
                Name = new String[jarray.length()];
                Phone = new String[jarray.length()];
                Date = new String[jarray.length()];

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                     Email[i] = jobj.getString("Email");

                    Name[i] = jobj.getString("Name");
                    Phone[i] = jobj.getString("Phone");
                    Date[i] = jobj.getString("Date");




                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        return result;
    }
```